# lazy list reconstructed based on concreteness of its type?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, typeclass, monomorphism-restriction

I wrote a simple (and unserious) prime number generator in Haskell, with mutually-recursive definitions for generating the primes and for determining the primeness of a number:

```
primes :: (Integral a) => [a]
primes = 2 : filter isPrime [3, 5..]

isPrime :: (Integral a) => a -> Bool
isPrime m = all (indiv m) (takeWhile (<= (intSqrt m)) primes)

intSqrt :: (Integral a) => a -> a
intSqrt 1 = 1
intSqrt n = div (m + (div (n - 1) m)) 2
  where m = intSqrt (n - 1)

indiv :: (Integral a) => a -> a -> Bool
indiv m n = rem m n /= 0
```

I noticed that it seems to reconstruct the sublist of already-generated primes with every reference to `primes`:

```
*Main> take 200 primes
[2,3,5,7, ..., 1223]
(2.70 secs, 446142856 bytes)
*Main> take 200 primes
[2,3,5,7, ..., 1223]
(2.49 secs, 445803544 bytes)
```

But when I change the type annotations to use a concrete integral type, such as

```
primes :: [Integer]
isPrime :: Integer -> Bool
```

each prime is only generated once:

```
*Main> :r
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Primes.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main> take 200 primes
[2,3,5,7, ..., 1223]
(2.15 secs, 378377848 bytes)
*Main> take 200 primes
[2,3,5,7, ..., 1223]
(0.01 secs, 1626984 bytes)
```

Seems curious to me. Any particular reason this is happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you say

```
primes :: [Integer]
```

then `primes` is a constant, but when you say

```
primes :: (Integral a) => [a]
```

then it is a function with a hidden parameter: the `Integral` instance for whichever type `a` is. And like other functions, it will recompute its results when you call it with the same parameters (unless you've explicitly memoised it).

Comment: This surprising lack of sharing computation that occurs with "polymorphic constants" is the reason the [monomorphism restriction](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction) was introduced.

Comment: Ah, thank you. That makes sense in retrospect (although I'm unsure why it can't be specialized and thus memoized as needed).

Comment: @JamesCunningham GHC recognises a [SPECIALISED](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/pragmas.html#specialize-pragma) pragma (although I've not used it myself).

Comment: @JamesCunningham: I agree, it seems like we should be able to have automatic specialization, particularly since in most cases there are only a finite (and usually small) number of instances for any class. Perhaps the fact that there _can_ be an infinity of instances is the fly in the ointment for this approach, although it seems like that situation could be detected and no automatic specialization applied in that case.

Comment: Also, I guess if you had multiple class-constrained type variables in a signature, you'd end up with a Cartesian product of specializations, so that could get quite large.